# How to only allow an object to be created if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have created this constructor to store information about football coaches.

```
String name;
Team team;

public Coach(String name, Team team){
    this.name = name;
    this.team = team;
}
```

Coach objects are then created using 'name' and 'team' inputted by the user

```
String name = nameField.getText();
Team team = (Team) teamComboBox.getSelectedItem();

// creates coach object
Coach coach = new Coach(name, team);
```

My question is, how do I only allow 1 coach object to be created for each team selected?

Comment: Do you want to prevent duplicates or only ever create one, reusing it if it already exists?

Comment: I want to stop two coaches from being added for the same team, if that makes sense?

Comment: Maintain a map or set of coaches for each team. Each time you're about to create a new coach, check the map or set first.

Comment: Sorry to sound basic, but how do I do that?

Comment: The duplicate contains a number of examples. I don't know your entire object graph, but you could have a `Map<Team, Set<Coach>> teams;`. When creating a `Coach`, you could check `teams.get(team).add(coach);` (returns a boolean) to see if it was already in there.

Comment: What do you want to have happen instead of having two coaches?

Comment: An error message that states only 1 coach per team.